# How can I draw the switch in circuitikz automatically?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,-
    3)  --(-2,-3)   to[L, l={$L$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (-2,0)--(0,0) to [rmeter, t=$ A_2 $] ++(2,0)--(2.3,.3);  
    \draw (2.3,0)node[below]{$K$} -- (4,0) to[R={$R$},*-,european resistors](4,-3) -- (0,-
    3) to [rmeter, t=$ V_2 $] (0,0);
    \draw[fill=white] (2.3,0) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \draw[fill=white] (2,0) circle[radius=1.5pt];
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look at the manual, section "switches", you'll find a `to[nos]` path element that probably does what you want (`nos` stands for *normally open switch*). You also have "cute" (more stylable) options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the manual, hidden under the section "Switches, buttons and jumpers", you have this (for example, there are several versions:)

[image]

you can use it for example like:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,-3)  --(-2,-3)
        to[L, l={$L$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (-2,0)
        --(0,0) to [rmeter, t=$ A_2 $] ++(2,0)
        to[cute open switch, l_=$K$] (4,0)
        to[R={$R$},*-](4,-3)
        -- (0,-3) to [rmeter, t=$ V_2 $] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of notes:

1. do not add a new line between a minus sign and the number. In this case, it works, but you can have a lot of surprises down the line;
2. if you use `europeanresistors` as a global option, there is no need to repeat it in the component;
3. Also, you mix a lot absolute and relative coordinates, which also is not optimal. As a personal advice, learn to use relative, named and orthogonal coordinates (it's explained in the `circuitikz` tutorials), your code will be much more reusable.

If the switch is too fat for you, you can tweak it, again, as explained in the manual.

As an example, I would write your circuit like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[EFvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
% add here your "preferred style option"; if you have several, you can
% then create a style-file (see section 3.3 in the manual)
\ctikzset{european resistors, 
    bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.25,
}
% define special components, you can reuse them also
\tikzset{longL/.style={
    L, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(start)   % name start and key positions
        to[longL, l={$L$}] ++(0,-3) coordinate(botL)
        (start) -- ++(2,0) coordinate(vtop)
        to [rmeter, t=$A_2$] ++(2,0)
        to[cute open switch, l_=$K$] ++(2,0)
        to[R=$R$] ++(0,-3) -- (botL)
        % here the first coordinate is: horizontal from botL, vertical from vtop
        (botL-|vtop) to [rmeter, t=$V_2$] (vtop)
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

now you have reusable "style" commands, and a `longL` element. Moreover, if you want this circuit as part of another, you just have to change from where it starts --- the (0,0) at the top.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! +1. however I would remove dot bove resistor :-)

Comment: @Rmano How about syntax `(botL-|vtop)`?

Comment: @ThuyNguyen It's the orthogonal coordinate system; I have added a comment. You can look at them here: https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.